# how do i get windows 7 to display results of running python and tkinter in a window or html doc

Tags: python, html, windows-7-x64

I am running windows 7. Python runs but I cannot seem to have the results shown on screen. It just seems to run in background.
I have tried to run through chrome and IE. The program runs from a shortcut on desktop, but does not show output.

Comment: What code are you using? Minimal working example will expedite this process remarkably :) And wait... you're running python code through a desktop shortcut..... this sounds very suspicious

Comment: I use "C:\Python27\pythonw2.7.exe hello.py" as shortcut to the py program which can be a simple as print "hello world". It obviously runs but I get no window to see result, unless I use the interactive mode which of course has its own window. I would like to use tinker in a GUI but would be happy if I could just get "Hello World!